# Are the borders of Eretz Israel going to be the same in regard to the Torah when moshiach comes?

Tags: history, messiah, eretz-yisrael, geography, ymoth-hamoshiach

I have read before an opinion that they are not going to be the same borders, I am hoping for some backup information.

Comment: keep in mind that there are two approaches - the borders De-jure - what's described in the Torah, and De-facto - all the lands that we conquer are considered Eretz Israel, as King David extended the borders into Sirya and Lebanon.

Comment: I'm not sure which borders you refer to. The current borders of the state of Israel? The current borders of where one is obligated in Teruma and Maaser? Various borders listed at different places in Tanakh? Which?

Comment: @DoubleAA He is talking about the concept of the expansion of all the borders like is discussed in Navi, midrash and chassidut. The size of the Temple itself is expanded, the boundary of Jerusalem is expanded, and ultimately the borders of Israel expand to encompass the entire world. And it has nothing to with military conquest either. This is discussed in more detail with sources by the Lubavitcher Rebbe in his Chassidic discourses.

Comment: @Yaakov Deane Where in Tanakh is it indicated thet one day Israel will encompass the whole world? Daniel 2 and Daniel 7?

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau If the question comes off hold, I will, bli neder, try to put an answer together from the Rebbe's discourse. All of this subject is dealing with later stages of the Days of Moshiach.

Comment: @Yaacov how do you know that?

Comment: @DoubleAA I am familiar with the teachings of the Rebbe on this. It's not a chiddush. It's known. If you look at the individual who is asking and his interests (questions, etc.) you see where his knowledge is coming from.

Comment: @Yaacov interesting guess